# In Python, how do I change the type of a column of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, int

I have an array which I created like this:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=",", names=True)
```

so I call each column by it's title name. All columns are float64 and I'm trying this:

```
data[title]=data[title].astype(int)
```

and some variables of int like int64 or S10.... but it won't work.  only want to change some of the columns, not all.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: If you add `dtype=None` to the `genfromtxt`, it will deduce the type.  Currently it's using `float` as the default type.  You can also spell out dtypes in detail.  It is difficult to change field dtypes after the structured array has been created.